# How to write a firestore rule to query another collection, where value is equal to some value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The roles collection have a field of uid that references a real user id(request.auth.id) and a roles field that contains an array of role(s).

```
function hasRoles(rsc, roles) {
    return (rsc in roles);
}
```

// The rule

```
allow write, create: if hasRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles).data.uid == request.auth.uid, ['super_admin']);
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that you would like to know how to write the inner code of the function. What did you already try??

Comment: I have tried the above, and also tried `(rsc.data.roles in roles)` in the hasRoles function because the roles collection have a roles field. I can tell what I'm missing though.

Comment: Can you show the document containing the role? Screenshot of the collection and document fields

Comment: Updated the question with the screenshot @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preamble**: The following answer makes the assumption that the  ID of the ‘role‘ document correspond to the user’s UID, which is not exactly your data model. You’ll need to slightly adapt your data  model.

To [get the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) you need to do:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid))`

Then you want to get the value of the ‘role‘ field:

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role`

Then you need to use the `in` operator of [`list`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List), to check if the `super_admin` string is in the array field `role`:

`"super_admin" in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role`

You can also test more than one role at a time with [`List#hasAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAll):

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role.hasAll(["editor", "publisher"])`

These will return `true` or `false` (note that I haven’t tested it, being commuting and writing on a smartphone, so there may be some fine tuning to be done! :-))

Comment: Note: This would work only after using the user's ID as the ID of the documents in the `roles` collection.

Comment: Another note, if you plan to nest this solution in a function, make sure it can handle things like the `roles/$(request.auth.uid)` document not existing, because if you try to access `data.role` on a non-existant document the entire rule will crash, evaluate as `false` and deny access.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that @samthecodingman

Comment: @samthecodingman, thank you, I guess I will use uid as the id of the role, I had a uid field in the roles item from previous but.

Comment: Ok I see the problem now! sorry I din’t understand that the UID was **in** the doc, my current screen is small. @samthecodingman you may write an answer! In any case thanks for the heads up.